# WebKit.NET C#: CSS Gradient (Radial)

Tags: c#, html, css, gradient, webkit.net

I am developing a wins form in C# utilizing WebKit.Net webBrowser component to create HTML5 web pages. How could I possibly styling such that it creates a radial gradient using WebKit.Net? I have tried something like following, but only -webkit-gradient works.

```
background: rgb(249,225,225); /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(249,225,225,1) 0%, rgba(248,197,197,1) 38%, rgba(243,130,130,1) 87%, rgba(251,32,32,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%,rgba(249,225,225,1)), color-stop(38%,rgba(248,197,197,1)), color-stop(87%,rgba(243,130,130,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(251,32,32,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(249,225,225,1) 0%,rgba(248,197,197,1) 38%,rgba(243,130,130,1) 87%,rgba(251,32,32,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
```

I wonder WebKit.Net can use any other syntax besides -webkit-gradient? Because I was trying to get a ellipse shape instead of a circle.

Was new guy here, appreciate if anyone here could resolve this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reseached for while and got a solution for .NET :) It can actually be easily done in [Open Webkit Sharp](http://code.google.com/p/open-webkit-sharp/) :) It supports the latest features of HTML5 & CSS3.